# Использование нестандартынх шрифтов Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, шрифты, импорт

Как можно импортировать и использовать сторонний шрифт в формате .ttf в программу Tkinter?

Comment: сильно сторонний ? выбрать из кучи похожий не вариант ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614027/list-available-font-families-in-tkinter/44230092#44230092

Comment: Да, у меня это файл со шрифтом которого нет в списке font.families().